# how to construct this equalizer

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory

If *X* is a topological space and (*U*$_i$)$_i$$_\in$$_I$ is a family of open subsets of *X*, write *U* = $\cup$$_i$$_\in$$_I$ *U$_i$* and *U$_i$$_j$* = *U$_i$ $\cap$ U$_j$* for *i, j* $\in$ *I*.

(i) if *f, g: U* $\to$ **R** are continuous functions such that *f*|*U$_i$* = *g|U$_i$*, then *f = g*

(ii) if (*f*$_i$: *U*$_i$)$_i$$_\in$$_I$ is a family of continuous real-valued functions such that *f$_i$*|*U$_i$$_j$* = *f$_j$*|*U$_i$$_j$* for all i, j, then there exist a unique continuous *f: U* $\to$ **R** with *f*|*U$_i$* = *f$_i$* for all i.

For every oepn *V* $\subseteq$ *X*, define $\varGamma$(*V*) = {continuous *f: V*$\to$ **R**} and $\varGamma$(*W*) $\to$$\varGamma$(*V*) to be the restriction for *V* a subset of *W*. Then properties (i)(ii) say that $\varGamma$(*U*) is the equalizer of the family of maps $\varGamma$(*U$_i$*) $\to$$\varGamma$(*V$_i$*).

I am confused by the last sentence. How (i)(ii) give that conclusion? What are the two maps $\varGamma$(*U$_i$*) $\to$$\varGamma$(*V$_i$*) which consist of part of the equalizer? And I take it the map from $\varGamma$(*U*) $\to$$\varGamma$(*U$_i$*) is the restriction?

I've also tried thinking about it as presheaf functor, still not quite clear.  Thank you SO MUCH!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the category of vector spaces we have the following diagram:

$$\prod_{i\in I}\Gamma(U_i)\begin{array}{c}\stackrel \alpha\longrightarrow\\ \stackrel \beta \longrightarrow \end{array}\prod_{(i,j)\in I\times I} \Gamma(U_{ij}),$$
where \begin{eqnarray*}\alpha(\{f_i\}_{i\in I})&=& \{f_i|U_{ij}\}_{i,j},\\
\beta(\{f_i\}_{i\in I})&=& \{f_j|U_{ij}\}_{i,j}.
\end{eqnarray*}

From (i), (ii) we know that the equaliser of this diagram is $\Gamma(U)$:

$$\Gamma(U)\stackrel\iota\longrightarrow\prod_{i\in I}\Gamma(U_i)\begin{array}{c}\stackrel \alpha\longrightarrow\\ \stackrel \beta \longrightarrow \end{array}\prod_{(i,j)\in I\times I} \Gamma(U_{ij})$$
Here $\iota(f)=\{f|U_i\}_i$.